# Good Python 2 audio module

Tags: python, audio, module, wav, py2app

What is a good module for playing wav files for Python 2 that would also be supported by py2app? (no pygame)

I just need it to be able to play a simple wav file.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [PyAudio](http://people.csail.mit.edu/hubert/pyaudio/). I found some examples like [this](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/18021-Phonon-in-standalone-app-via-py2app-backend-plugin-error?s=f8b2230eb41acfa8667a5f3939e80278&p=93574#post93574) where it has been used with py2app